# kali linux encrypting passwords with yescrypt - how to change?

Tags: password-cracking, kali-linux, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I'm using John The Ripper for password cracking and adding new users/passwords to test it out.  When I create a new user and password, the hash starts with `$y$` which is from yescrypt.  When testing a new password cracker - `hashcat` - it apparently doesn't support that format.

Is there a way to change the hash method when creating a new password - `sudo passwd xxxx`?
Is there a way to get `hashcat` to work with this hash?

Comment: Actually you can use John The Ripper to crack $y$ (yescrypt) hashes.
Here is step-by-step example: https://youtu.be/tevAFN9O9lg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file.

Look for a the line:
`password       [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure yescrypt`

and change `yescrypt` to something like `sha512`:
`password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure sha512`

Before:

> kali:$y$j9T$Zvm8nb[redacted]

After:

> kali:$6$kin2RTFsKNkf[redacted]

There is a request to add yescrypt to hashcat.
https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/2816